# How to separate FileLoggingSession files of App and BackgroundTask?

Tags: logging, windows-runtime, uwp

Trying to trace using Windows.Foundation.Diagnostics [FileLoggingSession](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.diagnostics.fileloggingsession) I get a file in use exception when tracing from both app and background task. I found no way to configure the log file path or file name pattern. How are we supposed to use this in apps?

Comment: Why have multiple logging files? The singleton model as demonstrated here https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Logging may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> exception when tracing from both app and background task.

The app and background task are running on different processes. The app was running on the app container and the background task was running on the broker process. So you will get “file in use” exception when trying to write the same file from 2 different proceses.

As the tested, the log file name format is “Log-{session name}-0.etl”.
As a workaround, you can create different log sessions for app process and background process.

For example:

```
var appSession = new FileLoggingSession("app_log_session");

var backgroundSession = new FileLoggingSession("background_log_session");
```